# how to determine Time Series Model? Additive Multiplicative?

Tags: time-series

I am new to time series Analysis, and I have noted that there's only two kind of models: Additive or multiplicative.

I want to know if there's other cases where we can find a combination of both.
For example, if We have a Time Series with $S_t$ a complex Seasonality. Then the time serie formula will be like:

$$Y_t=T_t * [S_t(1) * S_t(2) + S_t(3)] + N_t$$

Does this case exist in Time Series Analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is an oversimplification (or incomplete). It is correct that a time series model that has multiple components can have additive or multiplicative interactions between those components; but there are many kinds of models (exponential smoothing, arima, unobserved component, etc.). A given forecast model can be mixed-- additive trend with multiplicative seasonality, or additive errors with multiplicative trend, etc.

Do you have particular data/phenomena in mind? I can imagine something like this:

- multiplicative week of year seasonality (not uncommon), where the high points are 10% above average and low points are 10% below
- additive phenomena that could be modeled like seasonality because it's so consistent, eg, customer A always orders 100 units in the first quarter of each year

In the latter case this could be modeled as a regressor rather than as seasonality. Otherwise, thinking about my (limited) knowledge of forecasting implementations I don't know how you would do it. Modeling multiple seasonal frequencies is difficult to find. SAS `proc ucm` can do it with the BLOCKSEASON statement, that's the only way I've done it and that was for doing seasonality of day of the week and week of the year.